# Error in Storing dynamic button label using SharedPreference in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, sharedpreferences

In my application I'm using a `Predefined Button` to `Dynamically Generate Button`. Buttons created with labels as Test1, Test2, Test 3 and so on. But after restarting application again all the `Dynamically generated Buttons` have `"New"` as their label on them.
 Code to add Buttons:

```
AlertDialog.Builder addreport = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        addreport.setTitle("Add New Button");
        LinearLayout addlayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        addlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        addlayout.setPadding(15,15,15,15);

        final EditText btnlabel = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        btnlabel.setHint("Enter btn label");
        addlayout.addView(btnlabel);

        addreport.setView(addlayout);
        addreport.setNeutralButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);

                    //final Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    btn.setText(btnlabel.getText());
                    btn.setId(i);
                    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
                    ll.addView(btn, lp);
                    i++;
                    btncount++;
                    Editor edit = preferences.edit();
                    edit.putString("btn"+btn.getId(), btn.getText().toString());
                    edit.putInt("count", btncount);
                    edit.commit();
                    return; 
                    }
            });
        AlertDialog adrptdialog = addreport.create();
        adrptdialog.show();
    }   
    }
```

SharedPreference Code to store:

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    //btncount = preferences.getInt("count", 0);
    String labels = preferences.getString("btn"+btn.getId(), "New");
    for( i=0;i<btncount;i++)
    {
        final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setId(i);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        btn1.setText(labels);
    ll.addView(btn1, lp);   
    }
```

Comment: //btncount = preferences.getInt("count", 0); 
this line is commented. So you'll never enter the for loop

Comment: have you checked contents of your shared preferences xml? you can do it by using DDMS

Comment: @nikis Shared Preference xml file contains same info that need to be shown as output in application but after restarting application have same labels

Comment: @blackbelt tried without commenting line but no expected result

Comment: the code is unclear, but the problem is here `String labels = preferences.getString("btn"+btn.getId(), "New");`. Are you sure that result of `getId()` corresponds to variable `i`?

Comment: @nikis No, so what should i use instead of getId()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
int btncount = preferences.getInt("count", 0);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
for( i=0;i<btncount;i++)
{
    String label = preferences.getString("btn"+i, "New");
    Button btn1 = new Button(this);
    btn1.setId(i);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
    btn1.setText(label);
    ll.addView(btn1, lp);   
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm but after adding one button then if i add second button the application crashes and shows error: `The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
` .

Comment: Try without the final on the button construction. I updated the code.

Comment: Here is a blog post about adding views programmatically http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-programmatically-generate.html Should be a good place to start.